# WriteAbortedException Java

Tags: java, android, caching, serialization, deserialization

I have the following method. The purpose of this method is to retrieve from the cache the stored arraylist.

```
  public ArrayList<T> read_arraylist_from_cache(File name){

    FileInputStream fis;
    ArrayList<T> returnlist = null;
    try {   
            fis = new FileInputStream(name);            
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

           //here I take the exception 
            returnlist = (ArrayList<T>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Cannot retrieve the arraylist from the cache", "Cannot retrieve the arraylist from the cache", e);
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return returnlist;
}
```

However when I'm trying to cast to ArrayList I'm taking a WriteAbortedException.
The ArrayList that I'm passing to aforementioned class is the following one:

```
 ArrayList <Product>
```

Where the product pojo is:

```
 public class Products implements Serializable{

 @JsonProperty
 private String prodnum;
     @JsonProperty
     private String brand;

      //get,set
  }
```

The method that I'm  using in order to store the arraylist to the cache is the following

```
   public void write_to_byte_array(ArrayList<T> list,File file){

    // write to byte array
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        Log.d("file not found", "file not found", e1);
    }

    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        Log.d("Create ObjectOutputStream object", "Create ObjectOutputStream object", e1);
    }


    try {
        oos.writeObject(list);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.d("Write ObjectOutputStream object to file", "Write ObjectOutputStream object to file", e1);
    }


    try {
        oos.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.d("Close the connection with the file", "Close the connection with the file", e1);
    }


}
```

The arratList list that I pass to the aforementioned method is an

```
        ArrayList<Products>
```

again, and the file is the same as the file that I wrote before. However I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you have a method called write_to_byte_array() that writes to a file?

Comment: To write the arrylist to the cache. The title that I gave is not correct. So, I use the write... to write the arrylist to the file and the read... to read the arraylist from the file

Comment: I can see what it does. The point is that the title is indeed incorrect. Method names should reflect purpose, not implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The [WriteAbortedException API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/WriteAbortedException.html) describes the issue rather well.

Did you catch anything in the log when writing the object you are attempting to read?

Have you checked what is returned by WriteAbortedException.getCause()?

Also, just a note, Your exception handling in `write_to_byte_array` really should be rethought.  If the FileOutputStream constructor fails, having been unable to find the file, you log it, and then continue on as if nothing is wrong, guaranteeing that you will throw a NullPointerException at the next try block, and once again carry on as if nothing is wrong, guaranteeing another NullPointerException at the next try block.